# How to use environment variables in docker args

Tags: environment-variables, devops

I am trying to write a Jenkins CI job that uses the docker plugin. The plugin is installed and what I want to do is pull a docker image to a jenkins client (that is configured to run docker) and then issue commands to the docker image. I need to use some environment variables (like env.WORKSPACE), but I can't seem to get that to work. Here is what my jenkins file looks like:

pipeline {
agent { label 'my_docker_jenkins_agent' }

```
options {
    timestamps()
}

stages {
    stage('docker test') {
        agent {
            docker {
                label 'my_docker_jenkins_agent'
                image 'docker_registry/test/f32-bld:0.1'
                registryUrl 'https://my_internal_registry.foo.com'
                registryCredentialsId '<credentials id not shown>'
                args '--mount src=${env.WORKSPACE}/my-build-dir,dst=/bld,type=bind'
            }
        }
        steps {
            script {
                blah
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I need to use the Jenkins WORKSPACE variable since that will change with each job that runs and jenkins is checking out the code for me into my-build-dir, but I can't get it to work. I get this error when I run the job:

java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'my_internal_registry.foo.com/docker_registry/test/f32-bld:0.1'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: '${env.WORKSPACE}/my-build-dir' mount path must be absolute.

Any idea how to pass the WORKSPACE variable?

Comment: Try with giving double quote like `args "--mount src=${env.WORKSPACE}/my-build-dir,dst=/bld,type=bind"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

Try with giving double quote like

`args "--mount src=${env.WORKSPACE}/my-build-dir,dst=/bld,type=bind"`